# Assigning vector elements a value associated with preceding matching value

Tags: r, vector, match, apply

I have a vector of alternating `TRUE` and `FALSE` values:

```
dat <- c(T,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F)
```

I'd like to number each instance of `TRUE` with a unique sequential number and to assign each `FALSE` value the number associated with the `TRUE` value preceding it.

therefore, my desired output using the example `dat` above (which has 4 `TRUE` values):

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

---

**What I tried**:

I've tried the following (which works), but I know there must be a simpler solution!!

```
whichT <- which(dat==T)
whichF <- which(dat==F)

l1 <- lapply(1:length(whichT),
  FUN = function(x) 
    which(whichF > whichT[x] & whichF < whichT[(x+1)]) 
)

l1[[length(l1)]] <- which(whichF > whichT[length(whichT)])

replaceFs <- unlist(
  lapply(1:length(whichT), 
    function(x) l1[[x]] <- rep(x,length(l1[[x]]))
  )
)

replaceTs <- 1:length(whichT)

dat2 <- dat
  dat2[whichT] <- replaceTs
  dat2[whichF] <- replaceFs

dat2
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

I need a simpler and quicker solution b/c my real data set is 181k rows long!

**Base R solutions preferred, but any solution works**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum(dat)` will do what you want.  When used in mathematical functions TRUE gets converted to 1 and FALSE to 0 so taking the cumulative sum will add 1 every time you see a TRUE and add nothing when there is a FALSE which is what you want.

```
dat <- c(T,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F)
cumsum(dat)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

`cumsum()` is the most straightforward way, however, you can also do:

```
Reduce("+", dat, accumulate = TRUE)

 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the indexing, it can be easily done with `cumsum` from `base R`.  Here, `TRUE/FALSE` gets coerced to 1/0 and when we do the cumulative sum, whereever there is 1, it gets increment by 1

```
cumsum(dat)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```